# JUnit5: Forward every method call on object to wrapper function

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

I have the following situation:

I have a class I want to test with JUnit/Mockito but I want to add some code that should be executed on every method call to that object.

For example say I want the test to fail if a call to the tested class takes more than a specific amount of time (ignore that functionality similar to that with `@Timeout` already exists, its just a simple example). What I have done until now is writing a method that takes a method/lambda as argument and does just that. A call would look like this:

`Object result = failOnTimeout( () -> testedInstance.calledMethod(x, y) );`

This has the drawback of me needing to remember to wrap every method call. Is there a better way that circumvents this? The ideal behavior I would want is something like this:

```
@BeforeAll
public void setup() {
    testedInstace = new testedClass();
    wrapMethodCall(testedInstance, failOnTimeout);
}

@Test
public void acualTest() {
    Object result = testedInstance.calledMethod(x, y); //Implicitly calls 'failOnTimeout'
    // ...
}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could let me know if this or a feature that would solve my problem exists.

Comment: You might consider using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to accomplish this.  In AOP, you write an 'aspect' that serves as code that can come-before, come-after, or replace existing code.  It gets woven in at either compile-time or load-time (depends on the aspect provider).  You have complete control over the method that you weave against  (e.g. all methods that start with 'test' in any class ending with 'Test'), as well as the aspect that you supply.

Comment: @JeffBennett AOP looks like a great tool for addressing this. The only problem is that I would like to keep my dependencies as minimal as possible as I am working on an already existing codebase. But this is definitely something I will play around with in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few obvious solutions in your situation.
Let's imagine that we have such a class:

```
public class TestedClass {
    public void calledMethod(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Alexander");
    }
}
```

### Mockito

First of all, you could use Mockito approach. And use `org.mockito.stubbing.Answer` class and `Mockito.spy(...)` method. For example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;

public class TestedClassTestMockitoWay {
    @Test
    void calledMethodTest() {
        TestedClass original = new TestedClass();
        TestedClass spy = Mockito.spy(original);
        Answer<Void> answer = new Answer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) {
                timeoutWrapper(() -> {
                    try {
                        invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
            private void timeoutWrapper(Runnable runnable) {
                //todo: timeout implementation
                System.out.println("before");
                runnable.run();
                System.out.println("after");
            }
        };
        doAnswer(answer).when(spy).calledMethod(anyInt(), anyInt());
        spy.calledMethod(1, 2);
    }
}
```

### Inheritance

The second option is inheritance of tested class. If your tested class isn't final, then you could just inherit it. For example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TestedClassTestInheritanceWay {
    @Test
    void calledMethodTest() {
        TimeoutTestedClass testedClass = new TimeoutTestedClass();
        testedClass.calledMethod(1, 2);
    }

    private static class TimeoutTestedClass extends TestedClass {
        @Override
        public void calledMethod(int x, int y) {
            timeoutWrapper(() -> super.calledMethod(x, y));
        }

        private void timeoutWrapper(Runnable runnable) {
            //todo: timeout implementation
            System.out.println("before");
            runnable.run();
            System.out.println("after");
        }
    }
}
```

### Decoration

Or if your tested class is final. You could just decorate them:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TestedClassTestCompositionWay {

    @Test
    void calledMethodTest() {
        TestedClass original = new TestedClass();
        TimeoutTestedClass testedClass = new TimeoutTestedClass(original);
        testedClass.calledMethod(1, 2);
    }

    private static class TimeoutTestedClass {

        private final TestedClass testedClass;

        private TimeoutTestedClass(TestedClass testedClass) {
            this.testedClass = testedClass;
        }

        public void calledMethod(int x, int y) {
            timeoutWrapper(() -> testedClass.calledMethod(x, y));
        }

        private void timeoutWrapper(Runnable runnable) {
            //todo: timeout implementation
            System.out.println("before");
            runnable.run();
            System.out.println("after");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Inheritance is something I thought about before but disregarded it is "too much boilerplate" per class/method. While this might not be the best reason to discard the approach I find your solution with Mockito to be exactly what I am looking for. I am quite new to the library and was therefore unaware of this possibility. Thank you very much.